# Alternative to UTF8Encoding class in .Net core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm porting some legacy code to .Net core and I'm almost done except for this class. I searched but couldn't find any. So is there after all any replacement or alternative to `System.Text.UTF8Encoding` class in .NET core?

Comment: you will have to define what functionality you need – there's native UTF8 strings, so no one can guess your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=UTF8

You should use Encoding.UTF8.

Comment: I wonder why this is not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: @VSG24 the site and the tip has been mentioned a lot on corefx repo as well as aspnet repos at GitHub but I bet not everyone has the time to review all the posts there.

Answer (score 0):

It exist but is not yet in a stable release.
This is the nuget package for `dnxcore50` which contain `UTF8Encoding`:

```
"System.Text.Encoding" : "4.0.11-beta-23509"
```